# AppleScript : How to get files in folder without hidden files?

Tags: macos, applescript

I actually have two questions.

How to exclude hidden files like .DS_STORE, Icon when I try to get files in folder ?
I've tried "**without invisibles**" but it seems not working.

How to set my var the_new_folder as an existing folder if already exists ?

Thanks for answers.

My code:

```
--
-- Get all files in a selected folder
-- For each file, create a folder with the same name and put the file in
--

tell application "Finder"
    set the_path to choose folder with prompt "Choose your folder..."
    my file_to_folder(the_path)
end tell

on file_to_folder(the_folder)
    tell application "Finder"

        -- HELP NEEDED HERE
        -- HOW TO EXCLUDE HIDDEN FILES (Like Icon, .DS_STORE, etc)
        set the_files to files of the_folder

        repeat with the_file in the_files

            -- Exclude folder in selection
            if kind of the_file is not "Folder" then
                set the_path to container of the_file
                set the_file_ext to name extension of the_file

                -- Remove extension of the file name
                set the_file_name to name of the_file as string
                set the_file_name to text 1 thru ((offset of the_file_ext in (the_file_name)) - 2) of the_file_name

                -- Make the new folder with the file name
                try
                    set the_new_folder to make new folder at the_path with properties {name:the_file_name}
                on error
                    -- HELP NEEDED HERE
                    -- HOW TO SET the_new_folder AS THE EXISTING FOLDER
                end try

                -- Move the file in the new folder
                move the_file to the_new_folder

            end if
        end repeat

    end tell
end file_to_folder

tell application "Finder"
    (display dialog ("It's done!") buttons {"Perfect!"})
end tell
```

Comment: The Finder considers the `AppleShowAllFiles` preference setting, if the key is set to false the invisible files are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `System Events` context instead of `Finder`:

- bypasses the problem with the `AppleShowAllFiles` preference<sup>[1]</sup>
- is much faster in general.

Using the `visible` property of `file` / `folder` objects in the `System Events` context allows you to *predictably* determine either *all* items, including hidden ones (by default), or only the *visible* ones (with `whose visible is true`):

```applescript
# Sample input path.
set the_path to POSIX path of (path to home folder)

tell application "System Events"

    set allVisibleFiles to files of folder the_path whose visible is true

end tell
```

Simply omit `whose visible is true` to include hidden files too.

---

The code for either referencing a preexisting folder or creating it on demand is essentially the same as in the `Finder` context:

```applescript
# Sample input path.
set the_path to POSIX path of (path to home folder)

# Sample subfolder name
set the_subfolder_name to "subfolder"

tell application "System Events"

    if folder (the_path & the_subfolder_name) exists then
        set subfolder to folder (the_path & the_subfolder_name)
    else
        set subfolder to make new folder at folder the_path ¬
          with properties {name: the_subfolder_name}
    end if

end tell
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> In order to *predictably* exclude hidden items, a `Finder`-based solution is not only cumbersome but has massive side effects:

- You need to determine the current state of the the `AppleShowAllFiles` preference (`defaults read com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles`),
- then turn it off.

  - then *kill* Finder to make the change take effect (it restarts automatically) - this will be visually disruptive
- then, after your code has run, restore it to its previous value.

  - then kill Finder *again* so that the restored value takes effect again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your first question is not a problem.  Your code works fine for me.

As for the second issue, the simplest method is to use the text representation of **the_path**, and simply build the new folder, and see if it already exists:

```
set the_path_Text to (the_path as text)
set try_Path to the_path_Text & the_file_name
if (folder try_Path) exists then
    set the_new_folder to (folder try_Path)
else
    set the_new_folder to make new folder at the_path with properties {name:the_file_name}
end if
```

If you are truly having difficulty with the first code section, please post a new question with more details, such as a copy of the **Result** section of the Script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It works perfectly!

Concerning the first section, I actually put the `AppleShowAllFiles` key to true like as said @vadian.

That's why the hidden files appear on my system.
There is a way to exclude them in script?

Comment: Are you saying that you did this in Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles True`  ?  If so, you can start off your script by turning it off via **do shell script** and then turn it back on at the end of the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, temporarily setting and restoring `AppleShowAllFiles` is not only cumbersome, but may have massive side effects, because in order for the changed setting to take effect, Finder must be _killed_ (and implicitly restarted) - potentially twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of you ! @mklement0 @craig-smith

You will find below the corrected code with your help!

If I share this code, you want to be cited for thanks?

```applescript
--
-- Get all files in a selected folder
-- For each file, create a folder with the same name and put the file in
--


-- Get user folder
set the_path to choose folder with prompt "Choose your folder..."
my file_to_folder(the_path)


on file_to_folder(the_folder)

    tell application "System Events"

        -- Get all files without hidden
        set the_files to files of the_folder whose visible is true

        repeat with the_file in the_files

            -- Remove extension of the file name
            set the_file_ext to name extension of the_file
            set the_file_name to name of the_file as string
            set the_file_name to text 1 thru ((offset of the_file_ext in (the_file_name)) - 2) of the_file_name

            -- Make a new folder or get the existing
            set the_path to POSIX path of the_folder
            if folder (the_path & the_file_name) exists then
                set the_new_folder to folder (the_path & the_file_name)
            else
                set the_new_folder to make new folder at folder the_path with properties {name:the_file_name}
            end if

            -- Move the file to the new folder
            move the_file to the_new_folder

        end repeat

    end tell
end file_to_folder


-- Ending dialog
display dialog ("It's done!") buttons {"Perfect!"}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vincent - where are you thinking of sharing this? I'm personally not worried about attribution if all you're doing is to incorporate the _techniques_ from my answer into your code. If you're _quoting_ from an answer, however, you should link back to it. By the way, `@`-addressing people only works in _comments_, and there only to address (with notification) the owner of the answer or someone else who's already commented. I only found this post of yours by accident, and Craig Smith may not have seen it.

Comment: Both Finder `tell` blocks are actually not needed (`display dialog` and `choose folder` are part of Standard Additions not of the Finder) and the handler is not required to be written "in order of execution"

Comment: While it's generally fine to accept your own answer, doing so for a rehashing of other answers _without explaining the code_ will not be helpful to future readers.
At the very least, up-vote those answers that helped you, but, frankly, given how specific the code is to _your_ needs and that your question never needed to contain that much code to ask a question of general interest, my recommendation is to delete this answer.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for your answer.
I prefer not delete this answer because the code could be used by another.
However, I checked your answer that helped me the most.
This is actually more in line with StackOverflow. :)

Comment: Thanks, Vincent. If you keep your answer, I suggest implementing the improvements that vadian suggested (no need for `tell application "Finder"` blocks, and no need for any parentheses in `display dialog "It's done!" buttons {"Perfect!"}`).